# Amazon CLI does not have acm service

Tags: linux, command-line, amazon-web-services

I have installed the Amazon CLI in my Linux instance using:

```
sudo apt-get install awscli
```

However when I show the help I only can see the following services:

```
autoscaling
cloudformation
cloudtrail
cloudwatch
configure
directconnect
dynamodb
ec2
elasticache
elasticbeanstalk
elastictranscoder
elb
help
iam
importexport
kinesis
opsworks
rds
redshift
route53
s3
s3api
ses
sns
sqs
storagegateway
sts
support
swf
```

But I need the acm service. In the version I get:

```
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-92-generic
```

I idea what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't effectively use the distro-provided aws cli because distro maintainers generally focus on stability so the version provided doesn't keep up with the leading edge of the aws-cli utility's capabilities. As you can see...

> The AWS CLI is updated frequently with support for new services and commands.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

You now have version 1.2.9, [released in late 2013](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI/2713515051988986).

You will want to use [pip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) or [the bundled installer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html).

I suspect you may want to remove what you've installed with apt-get, first.